# Inserção no MySQL com PHP não funciona por nada

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tentando criar uma página de cadastro e salvar os dados do usuário no MySQL, mas está impossível fazer isso. Já pesquisei na internet, mas aparentemente meu código está correto.

**Código SQL:**

```
    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS site;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS site.usuario (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `metodoPagamento` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `emailPagamento` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `tituloSite` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `linkSite` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `idiomaSite` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `permiteContato` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `usuarioCima` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php
      // estabelece conexão com o banco de dados
      $conexao = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'senha', 'site');

      // define variáveis e atribui valor vazio a todas
      $nome = $email = $senha = $metodoPagamento = $emailPagamento = $tituloSite = "";
      $linkSite = $idiomaSite = $permiteContato = $promo = "";

      function testaEntrada($dados)
      {
        $dados = trim($dados);
        $dados = stripslashes($dados);
        $dados = htmlspecialchars($dados);
        return $dados;
      }

      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
      {
        $nome = testaEntrada($_POST['nome']);
        echo("Nome = ".$nome."<br />");
        $email = testaEntrada($_POST['email']);
        echo("Email = ".$email."<br />");
        $senha = testaEntrada($_POST['senha']);
        echo("Senha = ".$senha."<br />");
        $metodoPagamento = testaEntrada($_POST['metodoPagamento']);
        echo("Metodo de Pagamento = ".$metodoPagamento."<br />");
        $emailPagamento = testaEntrada($_POST['emailPagamento']);
        echo("Email pagamento = ".$emailPagamento."<br />");
        $tituloSite = testaEntrada($_POST['tituloSite']);
        echo("Título do site = ".$tituloSite."<br />");
        $linkSite = testaEntrada($_POST['linkSite']);
        echo("Link do site = ".$linkSite."<br />");
        $idiomaSite = testaEntrada($_POST['idiomaSite']);
      }
      if($idiomaSite == 'Outro')
      {
        $idiomaSite = testaEntrada($_POST['outroIdioma']);
      }
      echo("Idioma do site = ".$idiomaSite."<br />");
      if (testaEntrada($_POST['permiteContato']) == 'sim') 
      {
        $permiteContato = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        $permiteContato = 0;
      }
      $promo = 1;
      $promo = (int) $_GET['promo'];
      if($promo == "" || $promo == 0) 
      {
        $promo = 1; 
      }
      echo("Permite o usuário ".$promo." entrar em contato comigo? ");
      if ($permiteContato == 1) 
      {
        echo "SIM<br />";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "NÃO<br />";
      }
      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
        echo "A conexão com o banco de dados falhou: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        mysqli_close($conexao);
      }
      else
      {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario(nome, email, senha, metodoPagamento, emailPagamento, tituloSite, linkSite, idiomaSite, permiteContato, usuarioCima)
              VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$senha', '$metodoPagamento', '$emailPagamento', '$tituloSite', '$linkSite', '$idiomaSite', $permiteContato, $promo)";
        if (mysqli_query($conexao,$sql)) 
        {
          echo ($nome . " você foi cadastrado com sucesso! Enviamos um email de confirmação para " . $email);
        }
        else
        {
          die('Erro: ' . mysql_error($conexao));
        }
      }
      mysqli_close($conexao);
    ?>
```

Quando rodo o código os `echo`s imprimem normalmente e abaixo aparece somente `Erro:`, não imprime. Qual erro está ocorrendo?

Comment: Reabri a pergunta, considerando que quem fechou não deve ter notado a presença de `mysql_` e `mysqli_` ao mesmo tempo no código.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se copiou e colou o erro está em abrir a conexão com mysql_connect e depois usar os metodos da class mysqli.

Quando utiliza, por exemplo, *mysql**i**_query()*, está chamando um metodo da class mysqli de uma forma que o php chama de "procedural". Essa forma é o mesmo que escrever mysqli::query().

Antes dessa class estar disponível o acesso á base de dados era feito feito através de funções e não de métodos de objetos. Neste caso se usa a função mysql_connect() para abrir uma conexão com a base de dados.

Na classe mysqli conexão é aberta logo pelo construtor da class. A forma mysqli é apenas um alias (uma outra forma de chamar esse construtor).

Resumindo: tem que decidir se vai usar **mysql** ou **mysqli**. Não pode alternar entre um e outro.

Comment: Usei somente o mysqli e funcionou. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento Manuel!

Comment: Sobre escolher mysql, mysqli o PDO, aqui tem informações que podem ajudar:
https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta alterar a seguinte linha

```
die('Erro: ' . mysql_error($conexao));
```

por esta

```
die('Erro: ' . mysqli_error($conexao));
```

Acho que assim o erro já aparece e fica mais fácil perceber o que está de errado.